# Some proofs of validity using Z3Py online and a strategy proposed by Nikolaj Bjorner

Tags: z3

Lemma: forall x : R, x <> 0 -> (x / x) = 1.

Proof:

```
  x = Real('x')

  s = Solver()

  s.add(Or(x >0, x < 0), Not(x/x ==1))

  print s.check()
```

and the output is :

```
  unsat
```

Qed.

Lemma: forall x y : R, x <> 0,  y <> 0 -> (x / x + y / y) = 2.

Proof:

```
x, y = Reals('x y')
s = Solver()
s.add(Or(x >0, x < 0), Or(y >0, y < 0), Not(x/x + y/y ==2))
print s.check()
```

and the output is:

```
unsat
```

Qed.

Lemma: forall x y : R, x <> 0, y <> 0 -> (x / x + x / y) = ((x + y) / y).

Proof:

```
x, y = Reals('x y')
s = Solver()
s.add(Or(x >0, x < 0), Or(y >0, y < 0), Not(x/x + x/y == (x+y)/y))
print s.check()
```

and the output is:

```
unsat
```

Qed.

These lemmas were proved using Coq + Maple  at

http://coq.inria.fr/V8.2pl1/contribs/MapleMode.Examples.html

Please let me know if my proofs with Z3Py are correct and if you know a more direct form to prove them using Z3Py.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slightly more compact way by using the "prove" command instead of the solver object.
For example:

```
x, y = Reals('x y')
prove(Implies(And(Or(x >0, x < 0), Or(y >0, y < 0)), (x/x + x/y == (x+y)/y)))
```

Comment: BTW, we can write `x != 0` instead of `Or(x > 0, x < 0)`.